# PHP, MySQL. Logical error. Condition match, but still executes "else"

Tags: php, mysql, ternary-operator

I want to get all the rows that were "given by" the "System"(should only return one row, cause only one row in the table meets that condition).
 But even tho it gets the row right, and givenBy's value is "System", it still returns "3" in the ternary operator.

So, I have this little piece of code, where 
   `$query = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM regtokens WHERE token = \'' . $token . '\''));`

Here is my Code :

```
echo $query['givenBy'];  //outputs "System"

$level = ($query['givenBy'] === 'System' ? 1 : 3);  

echo $level;             //outputs "3"
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Show us `var_dump($query['givenBy'], 'System' == $query['givenBy'])`

Comment: `string(8) " System " bool(false)`

Comment: there you go there are spaces in there

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: you can use `trim($query['givenBy'])` to eliminate them

Comment: ohh ... I see ... Thanks!!!
anyways ... any idea why could that be happening? ...

Comment: @P3t3r6: what type the `givenBy` column is? Is it a `char`?

Comment: @zerkms Nope, its `text`

Comment: use "==" instead of "===" after triming "givenBy". coz "===" tries to match the variable types as well

Comment: @P3t3r6: then there is a space in database stored.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to use [trim](http://php.net/trim) to remove empty spaces. i also prefer to use [strtolower](http://php.net/strtolower) to comparing this type of strings.

you can try like this:

```
$level = (trim(strtolower($query['givenBy'])) === 'system' ? 1 : 3);  

echo $level;
```